# Que estrutura é "de qualidade"?

Tags: gramática, sintaxe

Que estrutura é *de qualidade*? Por exemplo:

> Serviço de saúde de qualidade.

É um adjetivo?

Tem outros exemplos similares?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é um adjetivo (adjetivo é uma só palavra, como *bonito, rico, infantil*), mas é uma locução adjetiva: duas ou mais palavras que cumprem a função de um adjetivo (ver [artigo no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/locucao-adjectivaadjetiva-definicao/7270)). No teu exemplo, *de qualidade* caracteriza *política de saúde;* poderia ser substituído pelo adjetivo *excelente*, por exemplo.

Estas locuções adjetivas são muito comuns. O mais comum é serem formadas por uma preposição (*de* no teu exemplo) mais uma ou várias palavras, normalmente um substantivo. Mais exemplos (com a locução adjetiva em itálico):

> Argumento *de peso*
>   Pessoa *de consciência*
>   Dia *de calor*
>   Objeto *de valor*
>   Mania *das grandezas*
>   Gesto *de cortesia*
>   Assunto *de importância (vital/nacional/etc.)*

Estes exemplos têm em comum com o teu—“política de saúde *de qualidade*”—o facto de a preposição *de* estar muito esvaziada de significado, servindo apenas para ligar as palavras. Em muitos outros casos a preposição *de* mantém a sua conotação própria (procedência, origem, posse, material, ser parte de), e de certeza que já usaste muitas destas estruturas sem pestanejar:

> Homem *do norte*
>   Um livro *da Joana*
>   Camisa *de seda*
>   Perna *da mesa*

*De*, sendo uma preposição para todo o serviço, é a mais usada nestas locuções, mas também se usam outras:

> Fermento *para bolos*
>   Barco *a remos*
>   Fulano *sem vergonha*
>   Casa *em ruínas*

A preposição pode também introduzir um verbo ou uma expressão mais longas, incluindo expressões idiomáticas (não sei se estão todas em uso no Brasil):

> Máquina *de escrever*
>   Frio *de rachar* (muito frio)
>   Cozinheira *de mão-cheia* (muito boa)
>   Ambiente *de cortar à faca* (muito tenso)
>   Amigo *de longa data*
>   Obra *de se lhe tirar o chapéu* (admirável)
>   Investigação *para inglês ver* (só para manter as aparências)
>   Coisas *do arco da velha* (fantásticas)

Muitos conjuntos formados por substantivo + locução adjetiva tornaram-se pelo uso em expressões fixas (p.ex., “máquina *de escrever*”, “moinho *de vento*), ou *compostos sintáticos* na terminologia da *Gramática do Português* (Lisboa, 2013). Estas expressões fixas soam mal se forem separadas. De modo que dizemos “moinho *de vento* antigo” e não “moinho antigo *de vento*”. “Casa *em ruínas*” já não é uma dessas expressões fixas, e podemos perfeitamente separá-la em “casa antiga *em ruínas*”, que até soa melhor que “casa *em ruínas* antiga”.

O [Wikcionário](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/Categoria:Locu%C3%A7%C3%A3o_adjetiva_(Portugu%C3%AAs)) tem um lista enorme de locuções adjetivas idiomáticas. Inclui locuções que não começam por preposição, mas as começadas por *de* são de longe as mais numerosas.